# Are Heaviside-Lorentz unit and Gaussian unit natural units?

Tags: electromagnetism, units, definition, unit-conversion

I am studying electromagnetism and have encountered the Heaviside-Lorentz unit and Gaussian unit. In these unit systems, the constant $c$ keeps occurring. For example, the Maxwell equations are of this form. [image]

So, I think in these unit systems, $c$ is some nontrivial constant other than $1$. However upon reading the Wikipedia about natural units, it states that the Heaviside-Lorentz unit and the Gaussian unit are natural units and $c=1$. So I am confused. Why does $c$ keep occuring in the two units if $c$ is jus equal to $1$? Could anyone please explain?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units#Electromagnetism_units  : This is the link to the Wikipedia about natural units that I read.

Comment: It doesn't say they are natural units.

Comment: It says. "There are two main natural units for electromagnetism."

Comment: Oh that's poorly written. They become natural if you take $c=1$.

Comment: So, that means I can take $c$ not to be $1$? So, in the above Maxwell equations, $c$ is not $1$ and therefore not omitted?

Comment: Yes, unless you are specified to work in natural units, you are expected to keep the $c$'s in these electromagnetic unit systems. For a complete description of unit systems you can check the appendix in Jackson's book, Classical Electrodynamics, 3ed.